# How to establish SSH connection between two AMI EC2 instances by generating new key pair using ssh-keygen

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, devops, ec2-ami

I need to establish SSH connection between `2 AMI Ec2 instances`.
I have tried by generating new key pair with `ssh-keygen method`.
Even after copying public key `id_rsa.pub` from one instance to `authorized_keys` folder in another instance, I'm facing

> "Permission denied (publickey)" error.

I feel I might have missed some simple step in this process.

Please provide steps to be followed in establishing ssh connection between two AMI EC2 instances by generating new key pair using `ssh-keygen`?

Answer (score 0):

authoried_keys is not a folder, it is a file. Create the file: ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and copy the contents of the public key in the other machine. Once copied, ensure that security groups allow the ports.